# Python. Need to be sure the connection is made from the local machine?

Tags: python, security, http, ftp, twisted

Imagine you have a HTTP server on your local machine, this is a typical Python/Twisted application. This server is used to access your local data, server is used just as a GUI interface. So user can use his web browser or special application ( acts like a web browser ) to access his local data.

Now you want to be sure that only local user who physically sit near this machine get access to the HTTP server.

Also I will have FTP server and it must be protected the same way too.

At the moment I am running such code for my HTTP server:

```
class LocalSite(server.Site):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        if addr.host != '127.0.0.1':
            print 'WARNING connection from ' + str(addr)
            return None
        try:
            res = server.Site.buildProtocol(self, addr)
        except:
            res = None
        return res
```

So I am just check the IP address at the moment and I am not sure this is enough.
Is there any ways to emulate local IP from remote machine.? 
Well, If a bad guy get access over my OS I have no way to protect - but this is not my deal. My firewall and antivirus should care about this, right?

Anyway, I would like to listen any extra ideas about increase security of such HTTP server.

May be we can use MAC address to verify connection.?
Check the processes on local machine and detect which is actually executes connection?

We can use HTTPS, but in my understanding this acts in opposite direction: this is for user to trust to the server, not server to trust to the user.

Using CAPTCHA is a kind of solution. But I do not like this at all (it strains users) and this will not work for FTP server.

I am also use random port number every time application starts.

The type of internet connection is not defined - this is a p2p application. Any user in the WEB can use my software and it must be protected against remote access.

Comment: That should be quite fine. [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/411658/can-localhost-be-spoofed) question can elaborate.

Comment: Ok. That post is very close to mine question. However guys are talking about Linux (isn't it?) but i wish to handle any OS. And as I undertstand the packet may be accepted, but response will go off. So I  am also not agree with that. Any way! Thank for the post!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way you handled it is good enough. About it being cross-platform, I believe it is as Windows(starting from windows 7) too maps localhost to 127.0.0.1 but for previous versions, you have to define localhost in the main hosts file.

Comment: Thanks! However I am still going to add some extra protection, but only if this will be an easy solution. About localhost: on my WindowsXP I see "127.0.0.1       localhost" is in my hosts file. I suspect all XP users have this by default, right?